# warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc80.pdb' was not found after switching to vista

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista, windows-xp, warnings

I'm getting several of the following warnings in VS2005 on an old project after moving from my old XP to a new vista PC:

UnitTest++.vsnet2005.lib(TestRunner.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc80.pdb' was not found with 'c:\projects\blah.lib' or     at 'c:\projects\blah\debug\vc80.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info

I know that this warnign can be ignored but I don't like warnings. The warnings all relate to a third party library (UnitTest++) I'm statically linking to. I can't see how this can be related to vista but both PCs have the same quantity of vc80.pdb files in the same locations after a build so I am confused as to how to fix this issue. Any ideas welcome.

Edit: Ok it's gone away. Just in case anyone expeeriences any thing similar I did three things but not sure what clicked it over:

1: copy any old vc80.pdb next to the lib, built it, and then deleted the pdb

2: changed the properties->c/c++->debug information format from edit and continue to database only, built it, and switched it back again

3: rebuilt the third party library (this seems most likely but I'm sure this was the first thing I did yesterday to no effect...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to clean/rebuild UnitTest++ library projects (if it is build form sources)?